# android setting default preferences from java

Tags: android, default, sharedpreferences

as the title above has said, is there any way to set default value of a preference from java code ?

if it is done from the xml side, it should be android:defaultValue.

But, how to do it from the java side ??

THX for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default value specified in the preferences XML only applies when using a `PreferenceActivity` and its UI. However, if you take a look at the `SharedPreferences` object, all of the [`get`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) methods allow you to specify a default value to retrieve when the preference does not have a value yet. Now, you can combine both the preferences XML and Java default values using constants in the xml files.

For example, declare a `<string>` constant in a resource XML, then you can use it as the default value in the XML like so `defaultValue="@string/myDefaultValue"`. Then, in your java code you can do:

```
        sharedPrefs.getString("stringPreference", getString(R.string.myDefaultValue));
```